# how to add value to the labels present in detailsview on page load event

Tags: c#, asp.net, detailsview

i Have a DetailsView on the page which contains few labels and i want to put some value in those labels on pageload event.. but iam unable to assign values to labels here is my code

iam trying on both OnPreRender() and OnDataBound() events but iam getting nullpointer exceptions..

somebody help me in this..iam struggling for couple of days

```
 <asp:DetailsView ID="gv_wifisummery" runat="server" Width="550px"  
        AutoGenerateRows="true" ForeColor="#333333" CellPadding="3" 
        CellSpacing="3" OnPreRender="DetailsView2_DataBound" OnDataBound="check" >

        <Fields>
         <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Devices ">

             <ItemTemplate>
                 <asp:Label ID="lbldevices" runat="server" Text='devices'></asp:Label>
             </ItemTemplate>
         </asp:TemplateField>
          <asp:CommandField ShowEditButton="True" />
        </Fields>

        <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" Height="30px"/>
        <CommandRowStyle BackColor="White" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="Blue" />
        <FieldHeaderStyle Font-Bold="True" Width="150px" />                                  
        <FooterStyle Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
        <PagerStyle BackColor="#666666" ForeColor="White" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
        <RowStyle BackColor="#E3EAEB" Font-Size="12px" />
    </asp:DetailsView>
```

-============================================================================================

```
protected void DetailsView2_DataBound(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
    DetailsView myDetailsView = (DetailsView)sender;
    myDetailsView.ChangeMode(DetailsViewMode.Insert);
  //Insert
   if (myDetailsView.CurrentMode == DetailsViewMode.Insert)
  {
   ((Label)myDetailsView.FindControl("lbldevices")).Text =    DateTime.Now.ToString("M/d/yyyy HH:mm");
  }
 }




protected void check(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
DetailsView myDetailsView = (DetailsView)sender;

if (myDetailsView.CurrentMode == DetailsViewMode.Insert)
{
   // ((Label)myDetailsView.FindControl("lbldevices")).Text =   DateTime.Now.ToString("M/d/yyyy HH:mm");

 }

  ((Label)myDetailsView.FindControl("lbldevices")).Text = DateTime.Now.ToString("M/d/yyyy HH:mm");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

hi check first mydetailsViews.Rows.Count() > 0.
i think your detailview has no rows thats why it throws error.

try this...

```
        DataTable table = new DataTable();
        table.Columns.Add("Devices");

        DataRow dr = table.NewRow();

        dr["Devices"] = DateTime.Now.ToString("M/d/yyyy HH:mm");
        table.Rows.Add(dr);
        myDetailsView.DataSource = table;
        myDetailsView.DataBind();
```